# rewriting the code sequence using two floating point integers only

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to rewrite the code sequence using two floating point integers only.
I realize I would have to use temporary memory locations to hold intermediate values. I know nothing else.

> The following MIPS code calculates the floating-point expression E = A * B + C * D,where the addresses of A, B, C, D, and E are stored in R1, R2, R3, R4, and R5,respectively:

```
L.S F0, 0(R1)

L.S F1, 0(R2)

MUL.S F0, F0, F1

L.S F2, 0(R3)

L.S F3, 0(R4)

MUL.S F2, F2, F3

ADD.S F0, F0, F2

S.S F0, 0(R5)
```

Comment: What are "floating point integers" supposed to be?

Comment: I assume floating point values that represent exact integers.  If you know your values will always be integer, floating point is a bad choice, but that's the only sensible meaning for the phrase.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think OP meant floating point _registers_, not _integers_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to either store the intermediate result (e.g. A * B) onto memory or a free general purpose register, then compute the second multiplication (e.g. C * D), then retrieve the intermediate result to perform the addition.

For example (assuming `R1`-`R5` are in fact `$t1`-`$t5`)

```
text
 l.s $f0, 0($t1)
 l.s $f1, 0($t2)
 mul.s $f0, $f0, $f1
 s.s $f0, 0($t5)   # Here we store the intermediate value
 l.s $f0, 0($t3)
 l.s $f1, 0($t4)
 mul.s $f0, $f0, $f1
 l.s $f1, 0($t5)  # Retrieve intermediate value
 add.s $f0, $f0, $f1
 s.s $f0, 0($t5)
```

If you want to store the intermediate value onto a general purpose register (say $t6), then you would change

```
 s.s $f0, 0($t5)   # Here we store the intermediate value
```

to

```
 mfc1 $t6, $f0     # Copy intermediate value to $t6
```

and

```
 l.s $f1, 0($t5)  # Retrieve intermediate value
```

to

```
  mtc1 $t6, $f1
```